Is there any way we can make communication happen between pods running in AKS with RDS in azure?
The thing I want to achieve is pods running in AKS be able to connect with RDS running in AWS, the condition here is the RDS should not be publicly accessible.
I read the official aws documentation HERE, but still not sure if this works.

A Site-to-Site VPN connection between Azure and AWS can enable secure and private communications between resources in the two clouds. Create a VPN Gateway in the Azure VNet where your AKS cluster resides. Set up a VPN on the AWS side using the AWS Virtual Private Gateway attached to the VPC where your RDS instance is hosted. Establish a VPN connection between the two gateways. This allows secure traffic flow between the AKS pods and the AWS RDS instance.Using Azure ExpressRoute combined with AWS Direct Connect provides a more robust solution for integrating Azure services with AWS services.

Establish an ExpressRoute connection from your Azure network to a supported Direct Connect location.From the AWS side, configure Direct Connect to link to the same location.Configure the necessary routing between the two services to ensure private connectivity.If you are using a multi-cloud strategy, you might consider setting up a transit gateway in both AWS and Azure, which can be interconnected.

Deploy an AWS Transit Gateway in the VPC that hosts your RDS instance.Use Azure Virtual WAN as a hub to connect with AWS Transit Gateway.Establish a connection between Azure Virtual WAN and AWS Transit Gateway to route traffic securely. So to summarize- Set up the Azure VPN Gateway.
Set up the AWS VPN Gateway.
Configure the VPN connection between Azure and AWS.
Configure routing to ensure traffic between the AKS subnet and the AWS RDS subnet travels over the VPN.
Test connectivity to ensure that pods can communicate securely with the RDS instance.
